# What kind of attorney should I hire for a foreign real estate sale?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, international-transfer

I own real estate outside the US and I intend on selling it in the next couple of years. While I'm not a US citizen, I did marry one and I am in the process of getting a Green Card. I'm currently on an H1B.

This sale will probably come in at over $1MM and I want to hire a lawyer in the Bay Area who can help me bring this sort of money into the US and help me deal with any tax repercussions and interface with the lawyers/agents/party in the country of sale.

I've obviously never dealt with this before and I'm looking for pointers and suggestions as to which kind of lawyer to hire. Do specific kinds of lawyers deal with this scenario? If not, what would be the closest thing?

Answer (score 2):

I would talk to an immigration lawyer.  This sounds like the kind of thing that they'd deal with frequently.  As I understand it, your concern is mostly about managing the transfer, not the sale.  An immigration lawyer is going to see clients with overseas assets frequently.  If this isn't something that they do themselves, they can refer you appropriately.

In general when I'm looking for a lawyer, I start with the local bar association.  The one for [San Francisco](http://www.sfbar.org/lawyerreferrals/index.aspx).  If that's the wrong bay area, they are normally at the county level.  So you can find them by searching for bar association with the appropriate county or city name.  If you explain your problem briefly, they can direct you.